# Wildcard on CSS shorthands?

Tags: css, wildcard, shorthand

I currently have `margin-top:25px` on something, and I want to change the other 3 attributes using this shorthand:

```
/*Shorthand: <top> <right+left> <bottom>*/
margin: * 10px 50px;
```

What should I replace the * for in order to leave it on 25px? (and don't say 25px, because sometimes I won't know the previous margin-top value!)

Is there a way to do this? Or I must use:

```
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:50px;
margin-left:10px;
```

But I really want to use the shorthand >_<

Comment: Yup! you have to list them all out unfortunately.  Alternatively, you can maybe work in inherit, but that's not likely to be a viable solution.

Comment: http://lesscss.org/, http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: @JosephMarikle, edit: "`inherit` must be the only value in the declaration in order to work"

Comment: @ajax333221 that's funny... is it in the w3c?  Because chrome allows it: http://jsfiddle.net/8yqmm/

Comment: @JosephMarikle, well, I read it from here http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritvalue , but I guess it's wrong

Comment: @ajax333221 which is confusing... because sitepoint is a good references site. :P  They must mean it doesn't work on every browser or that because it isn't a standard that it could be different with differing browsers

Comment: @JosephMarikle, Don't ever use it, it don't work on: Opera, FireFox and IE. (only on Chrome and Safari seem to work)

Comment: @ajax333221 go figure. XD  And yes... that's what makes programming fun... I learn new things every day. :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but are you wanting to inherit the value of the top-margin, and that's why you don't always know the value? If that's the case, you might try:

```
margin: inherit 10px 50px;
```

Comment: I don't want to `inherit` the value, I just want to leave it with the value it have before the shorthand line. Also I just read that `inherit` don't work with shorthands http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritvalue

Comment: Interesting. Well, I guess we all just wasted any time we would have saved by using shorthand. Just type the damn thing out on three lines :P

Comment: my prev. comment is not 100% true, it can be used in a shorthand (although not in shorthandS), it can ONLY be used in this one `margin:inherit` because "inherit must be the only value in the declaration in order to work"